# iOS web app "Open this page in Maps?" popup when trying to open the Maps App

Tags: iphone, ios, html, web-applications, maps

I'm writing an iPhone web app using HTML5/CSS3. I need to embed a link to open a built-in maps app from my web app. To open a location on the map I redirect mobile Safari to URL like this:

```
http://maps.google.com?q=Business+Name%26+Street+Address+City+State+Zip
```

In this case if a user taps on this link the iPhone opens up the maps app and displays the location specified in the URL.

But when I need to provide a URL for driving directions to a predefined location:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=1234+1st+ave+portland+or&daddr=Business+Name%26+Street+Address+City+State+Zip
```

I've encountered a strange situation when in some cases the iPhone displays a pupup message:

> Open this page in "Maps"?

with a choice of yes and no, and only if a user taps Yes, the maps opens up with directions. Note that this popup shows only for some addresses.

Is there any way to prevent this popup from showing at all?

Comment: I'm encountering this same pop up in a different scenario - when I try to invoke my own app's custom URL handler from a page being displayed in Mobile Safari - sometimes it just goes straight to the app and sometimes it says "Open this page in..." with Yes/No. I cannot figure out when this happens. I don't have a target="_blank" in my link... Ever figure it out?

Comment: @Danny: No, I gave up. Although now I checked it with iOS7 and the new Safari and the message doesn't come up anymore...

Answer (score 0):

I've created simple web page. Put a link and set google map link with query string value of particular address on src attribute of link element,run it to my iPhone 4.It is working fine, I'm not getting any window to ask it open on map app.

I noticed that you've used "saddr" as a query string parameter. You can replace that with "q" query string parameter.

Comment: I think this happens because of the "target=_blank" part of the link that opens that page, although I'm not entirely sure. The reason I used saddr and daddr is because I need this to display directions from and to address. But now, it seems like we need to also use maps.apple.com if you want this run under iOS6.